# wordpress get the title in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, title

in a PHP file is possible get the title of a post with

```
the_title();
```

is it possible, in a JS file, get the title of a post?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `document.title` to get title

Comment: Providing that the title of the document is set to the title of the post. I'm not WP expert, so I'd have a look through the DOM Tab on Firebug to see if you have an `wp`, `wordpress` or similar object set. That'll be where you find the name of the post. Otherwise, you'll just have to set it yourself.

Comment: @DanSchalow yes.getting post title by <?php wp_title(''); ?> in wordpress.find its object and get it.